# Problem with bash script that show volume level

Tags: linux, bash

I trying to make script that shows volume level of active volume sink. Here is code

```
#!/bin/bash

active_sink=$(pacmd list-sinks |awk '/* index:/{print $3}')
muted=$(pactl list sinks | perl -000ne 'if(/#${active_sink}/){/(Mute:.*)/; print "$1\n"}' | cut -f2 -d':' | cut -f2 -d' ')
vol=$(pactl list sinks | perl -000ne 'if(/#${active_sink}/){/(Volume:.*)/; print "$1\n"}' | cut -f1 -d'%' | tail -c 3
)

if [[ $muted = "no" ]]; then
    if [[ $vol -ge 65 ]]; then
        echo ~/.config/tint2/executors/icons/audio-volume-high.svg
        echo "$vol%"
    elif [[ $vol -ge 40 ]]; then
            echo ~/.config/tint2/executors/icons/audio-volume-medium.svg
            echo "$vol%"
    elif
           [[ $vol -ge 0 ]]; then
                echo ~/.config/tint2/executors/icons/audio-volume-low.svg
            echo "$vol%"        
    fi
else
    echo ~/.config/tint2/executors/icons/audio-volume-muted.svg
    echo "muted"
fi
```

I can't get this script to work, always get "muted".

Comment: Have you tried adding one more space on the third line (make it: ... | awk)? Spaces are big deal in bash.

Comment: What is the purpose of `$active_sink`?

Comment: This might help: [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/74329)

Comment: I am using bash on Ubuntu MATE 20.04 LTS, latest updates.  I used your script verbatim.  I cannot reproduce your problem.  It behaves correctly for various settings.

Comment: before the `if` block add `typeset -p active_sink muted vol` to diplay the contents of these variables; objective is to see if the variables contain what you think/expect they contain

Comment: if you're still having problems troubleshooting your code then consider updating the quesiton with the complete output from the 2x commands `pacmd list-sinks` and `pactl list sinks`

Comment: I don't work with `perl` but, assuming it functions like most linux/bash commands, this - `perl -000ne 'if(/#${active_sink}...'` - is *not* going to pass the value of `${active_sink}` to `perl` if simply because the `perl` script is wrapped in single quotes; perhaps try: `perl -000ne "if(/#${active_sink} ... "` (replace single quotes with double quotes)

Comment: So you have perl, Why don't you write it entirely with perl?

Comment: pactl list sinks: https://pastebin.com/4TddNF1W   pacmd list-sinks: https://pastebin.com/vrU7kE5Z   bash -x volume: https://pastebin.com/gDrqr3Fb

Answer (score 1):

I finally makes this thing to work, thanks @markp-fuso.
The problem was with `perl` and `${active_sink}`.

Final code that work with corrected **muted** and **vol**

```
#!/bin/bash

active_sink=$(pacmd list-sinks | awk '/* index:/{print $3}')
muted=$(pactl list sinks | grep -A14 -P "(\#|№)$active_sink" | awk '/Mute:/{print $2}')
vol=$(pactl list sinks | grep -A14 -P "(\#|№)$active_sink" | awk '/Volume: front-left:/{print $5}' | cut -f1 -d'%')

if [[ $muted = "no" ]]; then
    if [[ $vol -ge 65 ]]; then
        echo ~/.config/tint2/executors/icons/audio-volume-high.svg
        echo "$vol%"
    elif [[ $vol -ge 40 ]]; then
            echo ~/.config/tint2/executors/icons/audio-volume-medium.svg
            echo "$vol%"
    elif
           [[ $vol -ge 0 ]]; then
                echo ~/.config/tint2/executors/icons/audio-volume-low.svg
            echo "$vol%"        
    fi
else
    echo ~/.config/tint2/executors/icons/audio-volume-muted.svg
    echo "muted"
fi
```